# Is there a way to successful integrate Vue Storefront Nuxt with Algolia Search Routing in SSR?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, algolia, vue-storefront

Integrating [Algolia search](https://www.algolia.com/) with [VSF/Next branch](https://github.com/vuestorefront/vue-storefront/tree/next),  got the basics down.  Moving on to [routing](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/going-further/routing-urls/vue/#combining-with-nuxtjs).

With [Vanilla Nuxt](https://github.com/ed42311/algolia-nuxt-routes) the integration works as it should, although the workarounds are starting to stack.

**To Repro:**

1. pull && yarn && yarn run dev
2. http://192.168.1.4:3000/ && search for something
3. URL gets rewritten

checkout [VSF](https://github.com/ed42311/algolia-vsf-routes/tree/c1071e1b69450b59f53e088d5ca63e9b69cec71f) get a flicker re-render.

**To Repro:**

1. same as above except go to /Search
2. URL gets rewritten for a flash then render fires and goes back to original route

**What I’ve tried:**

1. Built the two repos in isolation and it seems to not be an issue with nuxt itself, more an issue with Vue StoreFront

**Reference:**
https://github.com/algolia/vue-instantsearch/issues/916 (tangential)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okee this has something to do with the nuxt comp passing the route `<nuxt :key="$route.fullPath"/>`

I was able to bypass it by doing this in the default template

```
    <div v-if="String($route.name) === 'Search___en'"><search/></div>
    <div v-else ><nuxt :key="$route.fullPath"/></div>
```

Basically bypassing the  comp with the key which was triggering a re-render because it uses the router under the hood... I'm guessing.

This is what eventually allowed me to use the integration code effectively: https://github.com/ed42311/algolia-vsf-routes/blob/main/layouts/default.vue#L11

While this solution works, Other suggestions are appreciated.